# Find documents not referenced by another table

Tags: python, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

Kind of a "not_eq_join", if that makes sense.

A have a table `A` with documents containing a `_key` field (it's the primary key), and another table `B` that has a `refs` field that points to `A._key`, this is btw a multi index so it may contain multiple references to documents in `A`. A is quite large, however B is not (probably less than 1000)

Entry in `A`:

```
{
  '_key': 'doc1',
  ...
}
```

Entry in `B`:

```
{
  'refs': ['doc1'],
  ...
}
```

The question is; how do I find documents in `A` that is **not** referenced by any document in `B` ?

My naive solution would be to retrieve all unique values from the `B.refs` multi index (but how to do that?) to an array variable, and then do something like: `.filter(refArray.contains(R.row['_key']).not_())` on the `A` selection (filtered by other criteria as well).

But this seems wrong, any better ideas?

Of course, I'd like to do this "as quickly as possible" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the number of documents referenced by `B` is small, your solution is probably the best one.

You can get the distinct values in an index (including multi-indexes) by writing `r.table('B').distinct({index: 'refs'})`.

If the the number of documents referenced by `B` is large compared to the size of `A`, this gets a lot harder to do efficiently.

Comment: I see. I didn't know `distinct()` could be used for that, nice! I'll accept this as answer since I sneaked in a second question.